# Load another .xib when orientation in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I used below code to implement that but it not work. Please give me some advices. Thanks much.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];

}
```

orientationChanged() function:

```
  - (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification{
        [self adjustViewsForOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
    }
```

adjustViewsForOrientation() function:

```
- (void) adjustViewsForOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        NSLog(@"load portrait view");
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DashBoardViewController" owner:self options:nil];
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"load landscapeview");
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DashBoardLandscapeView" owner:self options:nil];
    }
}
```

When run it always show DashBoardViewController.xib. In lanscape, it still shows DashBoardViewController.xib. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your not actually setting the view.

You need to do something like:

```
self.view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DashBoardLandscapeView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This will load the view from the Xib file, and set the current view to that view.

Don't forget to add the objectAtIndex:0 as you see in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: method instead of notifications

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if( UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) )
    {
        NSLog(@"load landscapeview");
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DashBoardLandscapeView" owner:self options:nil];
        //[self viewDidLoad];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"load portrait view");
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DashBoardViewController" owner:self options:nil];
        //[self viewDidLoad];
    }
}
```

Maybe you have to uncoment `[self viewDidLoad]` if you have som logic there.

Comment: @user3125692 have you try with viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Greg `viewDidLoad` is not safe to query for orientation.